# laravel 6 stating in test env after running a test

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I have written a test for part of my laravel 6 application, I have noticed that once I have run the test, the enviroment stays set to testing, and I cnnot understand why? I have manually run `php artisan config:clear` to reset it back to local.

```
<php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <!--<server name="APP_CONFIG_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/config.phpunit.php"/>-->
    <!--<server name="APP_SERVICES_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/services.phpunit.php"/>-->
    <!--<server name="APP_PACKAGES_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/packages.phpunit.php"/>-->
    <!--<server name="APP_ROUTES_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/routes.phpunit.php"/>-->
    <!--<server name="APP_EVENTS_CACHE" value="bootstrap/cache/events.phpunit.php"/>-->
</php>
```

This is my phpunit xml with the PHP settings above, and below is the actual test,

```
public function testAHostCanBeCreated()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $user = [
        'nickname' => $this->faker->userName,
        'host_id' => null
    ];

    $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/user', $user);

    $response->assertJsonStructure(['nickname', 'login_code', 'host_id']);
}
```

Can anyone offer any reason that the enviroment would not revert back to local, other laravel applications that run an older version do so?

Comment: You want it to run on testing environment or not? I did not understant. You said you want it to run on local environment, but in your question phpunit.xml `APP_ENV` is set to `value=testing`.

Comment: I am saying that once I run the test the entire application carries on being run in testing environment. It shouldn't surely it should revert back to local?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely related to Laravel's configuration caching.  For whatever reason, the test environment's config is being cached when you run your test suite and then it is sticking around afterwards; which it is not supposed to do.  I ran into this recently myself.

Laravel provides an artisan command to clear cached config settings:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

If that does address your problem you can configure PHPUnit to clear the cached config for you automatically by adding a `tearDownAfterClass()` call to your application's `TestCase.php` file:

```php
abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    public static function tearDownAfterClass() : void
    {
        $path = base_path('bootstrap/cache/config.php');
        if (file_exists($path)) {
            unlink($path);
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to make sure that the path referenced above is correct for your application.